# How do i read information from java debugger (or any other method)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Hi guys i would like to do something that sounds simple enough. but i have no idea where to start looking.

i have search Google a bit and haven't found anything related to what i want to do.

what i want to do is run a java application in debug, and print out the lines of code that run in the debugging process.

same as with going through code step by step, each step will print the line of code it stepped into.

i really have no idea where to start looking of how to so this. can someone help in giving me a direction.

thank you.

this is following another question (maybe i wasn't clear enough last time and didn't get a response)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506367/is-there-a-way-to-tap-into-eclipse-debugger-with-an-addon

Comment: You'll have more success getting answers to questions if you accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: but the answers did not help me and did not answer my question.
an answer needs to help me out on some level and not be unrelated.
when it is i accept it/

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds pretty similar to what the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) code coverage tool [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) offers. It shows you exactly which code is executed during the process it is monitoring.

It sounds like there is a problem you are trying to solve with your proposed solution though. What is the underlying problem?

Comment: i'll check emma see if that can help with what i want and get back to you. meanwhile +1